# To show: $\det\left[\begin{smallmatrix} -bc & b^2+bc & c^2+bc\\ a^2+ac & -ac & c^2+ac \\ a^2+ab & b^2+ab & -ab \end{smallmatrix}\right]=(ab+bc+ca)^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I've been having quite some trouble with this question.
I'm required to show that the below equation holds, by using properties of determinants (i.e. not allowed to directly expand the determinant before greatly simplifying it).

$$\begin{vmatrix}
-bc & b^2+bc & c^2+bc\\ 
a^2+ac & -ac & c^2+ac \\
a^2+ab & b^2+ab & -ab
\end{vmatrix}= (ab+bc+ca)^3$$

I tried everything:

$R_1\to R_1+R_2+R_3$ and similar transformations to extract that $ab+bc+ca$ term, but to no avail. $C_2\to C_1+C_2$ and $C_3\to C_3+C_1$ seemed to be a good lead, but I couldn't follow up.

How can I solve this question?

Comment: Try Gauss-Elimination

Comment: I just said that I should use properties of determinants, and not directly evaluate... @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Your answers and comments on both of my questions have been made without understanding the question. :/

Comment: first step $R_1 \to \frac{1}{a} (aR_1+bR_2+cR_3)$ then take $(ab+bc+ca)$ common from $R_1$

Comment: then $R_2 \to R_2 - (a+c)R_1$ and $R_3 \to R_3 - (a+b)R_1$ then take $(ab+bc+ca)$ common from $R_2$ and $R_3$ done.

Comment: I wonder if this can be argued from basic symmetry ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a=b=c=0$ then the equality holds.
WLG we assume $a\neq 0$ then
$$\begin{vmatrix}
-bc & b^2+bc & c^2+bc\\ 
a^2+ac & -ac & c^2+ac \\
a^2+ab & b^2+ab & -ab
\end{vmatrix}\\=\frac{1}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
a(-bc)+b(a^2+ac)+c(a^2+ab) & b(ac+bc+ca) & c(ac+bc+ca)\\ 
a^2+ac & -ac & c^2+ac \\
a^2+ab & b^2+ab & -ab
\end{vmatrix}\\(applying R_1 \to \frac1a(aR_1+bR_2+cR_3))\\
=\frac{1}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
a(ab+bc+ca) & b(ac+bc+ca) & c(ac+bc+ca)\\ 
a^2+ac & -ac & c^2+ac \\
a^2+ab & b^2+ab & -ab
\end{vmatrix}\\
=\frac{1}{a}(ab+bc+ca)\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c\\ 
a^2+ac & -ac & c^2+ac \\
a^2+ab & b^2+ab & -ab
\end{vmatrix}\\
=\frac{1}{a}(ab+bc+ca)\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c\\ 
0 & -(ab+bc+ac) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -(ab+bc+ca)
\end{vmatrix}\\
(applying R_2 \to R_2-(a+c)R_1\, and\, R_3 \to R_3-(a+b)R_1)\\
=(ab+bc+ca)^3$$

Comment: Separately you have to prove the case $a=0$ but this case is much easier. My solution was very similar, I got in the front of the determinant $\frac{1}{b+c}$ from the first column and $\frac{1}{c}$ from the second column (Gaussian elimination), then I brought this factor back inside the determinant to multiply the first row, which will make the first row $[-b\quad b\quad 1]$. Then add the second row to the first row and already $ab+bc+ac$ comes in the front of the determinant as a factor. Multiply the third row with $b$ and subtract it from the first row and it is almost solved.

Comment: @Momo : if $a=b=c=0$ we have nothing to prove. So, at least one of a,b,c must be non zero. If a is non zero we start with row 1 (as above), if b is non zero we start with row 2 and for c we start with row 3.

Comment: yes, as I said $a=0$ is easy (it also zeroes most of the entries in the original determinant). But it has to be mentioned for completness.

Answer (score 2):

I put my solution as an alternative (a little bit simpler). Write the original determinant as

$\begin{vmatrix}
-bc & b(b+c) & c(b+c)\\ 
a(a+c) & -ac & c(a+c) \\
a(a+b) & b(a+b) & -ab
\end{vmatrix}$

Multiply the first column with $b+c$ and the second one with c and bring $\frac{1}{c(b+c)}$ in front of the determinant:

$\frac{1}{c(b+c)}\begin{vmatrix}
-bc(b+c) & bc(b+c) & c(b+c)\\ 
a(a+c)(b+c) & -ac^2 & c(a+c) \\
a(a+b)(b+c) & bc(a+b) & -ab
\end{vmatrix}$

Multiply the first row by $\frac{1}{c(b+c)}$ in front of the determinant:

$\begin{vmatrix}
-b & b & 1\\ 
a(a+c)(b+c) & -ac^2 & c(a+c) \\
a(a+b)(b+c) & bc(a+b) & -ab
\end{vmatrix}$

Zero the first row and third column. Add the second column to the first column, multiply the third column with $-b$ and add it to the first column. Take the factors $ab+ac+bc$ out of the determinant:

$(ab+ac+bc)^2\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
a & -c & c(a+c) \\
a+b & b & -ab
\end{vmatrix}=
(ab+ac+bc)^2\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
a & -c & 0 \\
a+b & b & 0
\end{vmatrix}$

Now you may expand or continue the elimination in the same way.

The cases $c=0$ and $b+c=0$ must be solved separately (but these cases are much simpler).

Comment: "Multiply the first row with b+c" Did you mean column?

Comment: Yes. Corrected.

Comment: I wanted to give up the answer and just make a comment. But the idea of multiplying the columns and dividing the row looked cute and less verbose.

Comment: Agreed. +1 for you :)

Answer (score 2):

$A:=\begin{vmatrix}
-bc & b^2+bc & c^2+bc\\ 
a^2+ac & -ac & c^2+ac \\
a^2+ab & b^2+ab & -ab
\end{vmatrix}\enspace\enspace\enspace$ Shift: $\enspace C_2\to C_1$, $C_3\to C_2$, $C_1\to C_3\enspace$ => $\enspace B$

$B:=\begin{vmatrix}
b^2+bc & c^2+bc & -bc\\ 
-ac & c^2+ac & a^2+ac \\
b^2+ab & -ab & a^2+ab
\end{vmatrix}$

$C:=\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & (ab+ac+bc)^2\\ 
(ab+ac+bc)^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0& (ab+ac+bc)^2 & 0
\end{vmatrix}$

It's $|A|\cdot|B|=|A\cdot B|=|C|$ with $|A|=|B|$ (Sarrus rule *without* calculating, only a compare).

=> $|A|=\sqrt{|C|}=(ab+ac+bc)^3$

*Addition*:

In order to calculate the sign of the square root, it's sufficient to put in a value, e.g. $(a;b;c):=(1;1;0)$ .

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to check that the equality holds if $bc=0$, $ca=0$ or $ab=0$.

Let $bc=x$, $ca=y$ and $ab=z$. Then the determinant in L.H.S. can be written as

\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix} -x & x+zx/y & x+xy/z \\ y+yz/x & -y & y+xy/z \\ z+yz/x & z+zx/y & -z \end{vmatrix}&=\frac{1}{xyz}\begin{vmatrix}-x^2 & zx+xy & zx+xy \\ yz+xy & -y^2 & yz+xy\\ zx+yz & zx+yz & -z^2\end{vmatrix}\\
&=\begin{vmatrix}-x & y+z & y+z\\z+x&-y&z+x\\x+y&x+y&-z\end{vmatrix}\\
&=\begin{vmatrix}x+y+z & x+y+z & x+y+z\\z+x&-y&z+x\\x+y&x+y&-z\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(x+y+z)\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\z+x&-y&z+x\\x+y&x+y&-z\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(x+y+z)\begin{vmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\x+y+z&-y&x+y+z\\0&x+y&-(x+y+z)\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(x+y+z)^3
\end{align*}