# Determinant of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} -bc & b^2+bc & c^2+bc \\ a^2+ac & -ac & c^2+ac \\ a^2+ab & b^2+ab & -ab \end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: matrices, determinant

I started by adding $C_1$ goes to $C_1 + C_2 + C_3$.

After that well nothing seemed good to continue I have tried other steps too but it keeps getting more complex.

Comment: Why can't you just calculate the determinant normally? It would be faster than bothering with whatever this is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To show: $\det\left[\begin{smallmatrix} -bc & b^2+bc & c^2+bc\\ a^2+ac & -ac & c^2+ac \\ a^2+ab & b^2+ab & -ab \end{smallmatrix}\right]=(ab+bc+ca)^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016733/to-show-det-left-beginsmallmatrix-bc-b2bc-c2bc-a2ac-ac-c) – found quickly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cbegin%7Bvmatrix%7D%20-bc%20%26%20b%5E2%2Bbc%20%26%20c%5E2%2Bbc%20%5C%5C%20a%5E2%2Bac%20%26%20-ac%20%26%20c%5E2%2Bac%20%5C%5C%20a%5E2%2Bab%20%26%20b%5E2%2Bab%20%26%20-ab%20%5Cend%7Bvmatrix%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, our determinant it's $$-a^2b^2c^2+2abc\prod_{cyc}(a+b)+\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2(a+c)(b+c)=$$
$$=-w^6+2w^3(9uv^2-w^3)+\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2(c^2+3v^2)=$$

$$=-w^6+2w^3(9uv^2-w^3)+3w^6+3v^2(9v^4-6uw^3)=27v^6=(ab+ac+bc)^3.$$

Comment: I'm a high school student so I don't the cyc function

Comment: @Aashay agrawal It's a sing only. For example, $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a).$